# Exec script as root in autostart

Tags: linux, bash, debian, archlinux, autostart

I need to launch a log on script. This log on script contain several commands like : *cp, ln, *and* chown.*
But "chown" **need** to be **root** to be efficient. So my script is doing well, except the "chown" command.

My environnement :
Debian Jessie, LXDE.

My script (in /usr/local/bin/transfertPOL.sh) :

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #transfert de POL au démarrage de la session
    groupe=$(id -gn $1)
    uid=$(id -u $1)
    POL=/var/POL
    home=$(eval echo ~$1)
    lien=$home/.PlayOnLinux
    #changement de propriétaire du dossier
    sudo chown -h -R $1:$groupe $POL
    ln -s $POL $lien
    sudo chown -h -R $1:$groupe $lien
    #Copie des raccourcis sur le Bureau
    cp --preserve=ownership $POL/shorcuts/*.desktop $home/Desktop
```

My Desktop Entry in /etc/xdg/autostart/transfertPOL.desktop :

```
    [Desktop Entry]

    Type=Application

    Exec=sh /usr/local/bin/transfertPOL.sh
```

The Exec, I tried several things :

```
    Exec=sh /usr/local/bin/transfertPOL.sh #Work, but the chown don't

    Exec=/bin/bash/ -c "sudo /usr/local/bin/transfertPOL.sh" #doesn't work

    Exec=sudo sh /usr/local/bin/transfertPOL.sh #Work, but the chown don't
```

For this one, I've created a /etc/sudoers.d/transfert with

```
%users ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/transfertPOL.sh
```

The script is a symbolic link to PlayOnLinux local folder. Each users need to access to this specific POL folder. So when a user is logging, the chown is changing folder rights.

Do you have any idea to help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `sh` in the `Exec` command:

> `Exec=sudo sh /usr/local/bin/transfertPOL.sh`

So the sudoers entry:

> `%users ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/transfertPOL.sh`

wont run with root privileges.

You probably want to make your script executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/transfertPOL.sh
```

And change the `Exec` command to:

```
Exec=sudo /usr/local/bin/transfertPOL.sh
```

**BUT:** We got groups for that in Linux, try setting the correct group permissions on the files you want to read/write. You wont need that script at all then.